# MKMapView in a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, dictionary, mkmapview, tableview

I know that this is a common question; but the answers were not satisfying my demands. I trying to have a mapView in my tableview cell and I can do this; however when I scroll the map start to reload again which prevents smooth scrolling. Can somebody please help me?
Here is the code from the cellforrowatindexpath:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:   (NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
 {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"a";
FBGTimelineCell *cell = nil;
NSString *text = [object objectForKey:@"text"];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell =  [[FBGTimelineCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier detailText:text];
}

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
/*
cell.tableViewBackgroundColor = tableView.backgroundColor;
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
cell.cornerRadius = 2.0;
 [cell prepareForTableView:self.tableView indexPath:indexPath];
*/
UIView  *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:cell.frame];
view.layer.cornerRadius = 2;
view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
view.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;

view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
cell.backgroundView = view;

cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy"];
cell.dateLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[formatter stringFromDate:[object updatedAt]]];


cell.detailLabel.text = text;
cell.titleLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"title"];


if ([[object objectForKey:@"isEvent"] integerValue] == 1) {
    cell.photoView.hidden = YES;
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Events"];
    [query whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:[object objectForKey:@"event"]];
    query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){

        PFObject *object_event = [objects objectAtIndex:0];
    NSDate *date = [object_event objectForKey:@"date"];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM"];
    cell.eventMonthLabel.text = [[formatter stringFromDate:date] uppercaseString];
     [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd"];
    cell.eventDayLabel.text = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
    cell.eventInfoLabel.text = [object_event objectForKey:@"event"];
    NSString *str = [object_event objectForKey:@"details"];
        cell.eventDeatilsLabel.text = str;

    CGSize size2 = [[object objectForKey:@"text"] sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:13] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(275, 300) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByClipping];

    cell.backView.frame = CGRectMake(15, size2.height +58, 290, 150);

        self.mapView = [[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 150-65, 290, 65)];
        self.mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
        [self.mapView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
        [self.mapView setZoomEnabled:NO];
        [self.mapView setScrollEnabled:NO];

        CALayer *capa = self.mapView.layer;


        //I'm reserving enough room for the shadow
        UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.mapView.bounds
                                                       byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight)
                                                             cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0)];

        CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        maskLayer.frame = self.mapView.bounds;
        maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;

        [capa addSublayer:maskLayer];
        capa.mask = maskLayer;
        [cell.backView addSubview:self.mapView];

    UIView *separator = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 150-65, 290, 1)];
    separator.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHex:0xCBCBCB];
    [cell.backView addSubview:separator];

        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(15, size2.height +58, 290, 150);
        button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(openEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell addSubview:button];

    self.mapView.delegate = self;

    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion;
    MyLocation *location;
    PFGeoPoint *geo  =[object_event objectForKey:@"location"];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate =  CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(geo.latitude, geo.longitude);
    location = [[MyLocation alloc]initWithName:nil address:nil coordinate:coordinate];
    viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinate, 1.0*METERS_PER_MILE, 1.0*METERS_PER_MILE);
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:location];

    //(41.06783368386694, 29.034912586212158)

            [self.mapView setRegion:viewRegion animated:NO];




    }];


}else{
if ([[object objectForKey:@"isPhoto"] integerValue] == 1) {
    PFFile *theImage = [object objectForKey:@"photo"];
    cell.photoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    cell.backView.hidden = YES;
    if (object) {
        cell.photoView.file = [object objectForKey:@"photo"];


        // PFQTVC will take care of asynchronously downloading files, but will only load them when the tableview is not moving. If the data is there, let's load it right away.
        if ([cell.photoView.file isDataAvailable]) {
            [cell.photoView loadInBackground];
        }
    }

    NSData *imageData = [theImage getData];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    cell.photoView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    cell.photoView.frame = CGRectMake(cell.photoView.frame.origin.x, cell.photoView.frame.origin.y, cell.photoView.frame.size.width, [self frameForImage:image inImageViewAspectFit:cell.photoView].size.height);
}else{
    if ([[object objectForKey:@"isVideo"] integerValue] == 1) {
        cell.photoView.frame = CGRectMake(cell.photoView.frame.origin.x, cell.photoView.frame.origin.y, cell.photoView.frame.size.width, 175);
        cell.photoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        cell.photoView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

        playButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

        cell.backView.hidden = YES;
        [playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        playButton.frame = cell.photoView.frame;
        [cell addSubview:playButton];
        if ([object objectForKey:@"photo"]) {
                                    NSLog(@"das");
            cell.photoView.file = [object objectForKey:@"photo"];

            [cell.photoView loadInBackground];
            cell.photoView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
        }



         url = [NSURL URLWithString:[object objectForKey:@"video"]];
        [HCYoutubeParser thumbnailForYoutubeURL:url thumbnailSize:YouTubeThumbnailDefaultMaxQuality completeBlock:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) {

            if (!error) {
                if (![object objectForKey:@"photo"] ) {
                NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f);
                PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"videoImage.jpg" data:imageData];
                    NSLog(@"afsa");
                    [object setObject:imageFile forKey:@"photo"];
                    [object saveInBackground];
                    cell.photoView.image = image;

                }

                [playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playVideo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



            }
            }];

        cell.photoView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;


    }else
    cell.photoView.hidden = YES;
}
}




return cell;
```

}

Comment: where is the code where the cell is set?

Comment: static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"a";
    FBGTimelineCell *cell = nil;
    NSString *text = [object objectForKey:@"text"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell =  [[FBGTimelineCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier detailText:text];
    }

Comment: where do you add the map view to the cell?

Comment: in cellforrowatindexpath too

Comment: can you show the code for the entire method?

Comment: I updated the code up.

Comment: There is no tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:object method in UITableViewDataSource protocol...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITableView` scrolling speed is contingent upon how fast you can turn your data into pixels. Sweet macintosh do you have a lot of drawing code!!

### What can you do?

You can do all sorts of things to make your cells render faster: Draw the cells using `CoreGraphics`, cache them aggressively, or simplify them. As a rule of thumb, avoid complex UI element hierarchies.

Creating a `NSDateFormatter` can take up to a **half of a second**. Create one once, then hold a reference to it, or use a shared 'factory' for storing and creating `NSDateFormatter` instances.

There is also the chance that `MKMapView`'s scrolling competes with your `UITableView`'s scrolling. Disable scrolling on the `MKMapView`.

I would be amiss if I didn't tell you that the blocks you use may hold a reference to old cells to maintain a certain context/scope. This extra (potentially `strong`) reference keeps the cells in memory for a few seconds.

### Oh shoot, none of this works!

Try using `CoreGraphics` to get a `UIImage` from an **offscreen** `MKMapView`. Make sure you're not instantiating a new one each time, as that's probably expensive.

```
// Untested

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_mapView.frame.size, YES, 0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGAffineTransform flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake( 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, _mapView.frame.size.height);
CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipVertical);  

[_mapView.layer renderInContext:context];

UIImage *renderedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
// Do stuff with renderedImage
```

This image could be cached in indefinitely, maps don't change too often.

If you really want to get fancy, you could make a shared instance that holds this `MKMapView` and renders parts of a map. You could probably hook into the map tile rendering in `MKMapView` instead of using the code above.

### ***UPDATE:*** (6.24.14)

In iOS 7, you can use a specialized class (you don't need to hold onto an `MKMapView` anymore) to render maps, see this Gist I just wrote:

https://gist.github.com/fhsjaagshs/2e0471b41bb7666efa7d

This method is better because you don't need to hold onto an `MKMapView`, you don't need to write any potentially slow drawing code (`CoreGraphics` is CPU-based drawing, `MKMapSnapshotter` is probably GPU-based), and it's asynchronous! You can drop a `UIActivityIndicatorView` into your cell, and when the callback loads, kill it and replace it with the `UIImage`.

Comment: Great code example for `MKMapSnapshotter` in your Gist, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid any allocation of view/object out side of following line.

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell =  [[FBGTimelineCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier detailText:text];

    // Set Cell background View

    // Create Map View Here

    if(!self.mapview)
    {
        // Alloc Here.
    }
}
```

Comment: But still the map will reload.